# Downloading large file (> 100mb) on Honeycomb in AsyncTask slows UI, possibly because of GC?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a private inner class called DownloadFileAsyncTask in one of my activities. I've attached it:

```
private class DownloadFileAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Boolean> {
    private static final String TAG = "DownloadFileAsyncTask";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        mWifiLock           = manager.createWifiLock("wifilock");

        mWifiLock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(URL... params) {
        try {
            URLConnection urlConnection = params[0].openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream      in  = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("archive.zip", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            int fileSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            if (fileSize == 0) {
                return false;
            }

            int downloadedSize = 0;

            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int count   = 0;

            while ((count = in.read(data)) != -1) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Download cancelled.");

                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    return false;
                }

                out.write(data, 0, count);
                downloadedSize += count;

                publishProgress(downloadedSize, fileSize);
            }

            out.close();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground()", ex);

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        int downloadedSize = values[0];
        int fileSize       = values[1];

        int progressPercent = ((int) ((downloadedSize / (float) fileSize) * 100));

        mDownloadButton.setText(String.format("%.1f MB", downloadedSize / 1048576f));
        mProgressBar.setProgress(progressPercent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mWifiLock.release();
    }
}
```

This code works. The file is downloaded and my ProgressBar is updated correctly. I also have a cancel button the user can press to close the download. This also works, however, when I press the button it takes a few seconds for the button press to register (I am testing on hardware). When I look at logcat during the download, I see a lot of garbage collection happening. In fact, it seems constant. I know that the GC can cause delays in the UI and my theory is that is what is happening here. Has anyone experienced this before? Is there a better way to perform a file download?

**EDIT:**

Calling publishProgress() at the end of every iteration of the main loop was causing the delays. Here is updated code for doInBackground() to solve the issue:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(URL... params) {
    try {
        URLConnection urlConnection = params[0].openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();

        BufferedInputStream  in  = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(openFileOutput("archive.zip", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));

        int fileSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        if (fileSize == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        int downloadedSize = 0;

        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int count   = 0;

        Calendar lastUpdate = Calendar.getInstance();

        while ((count = in.read(data)) != -1) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Download cancelled.");

                out.close();
                in.close();
                return false;
            }

            out.write(data, 0, count);
            downloadedSize += count;

            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            if (now.getTimeInMillis() - lastUpdate.getTimeInMillis() >= 500) {
                lastUpdate = now;
                publishProgress(downloadedSize, fileSize);
            }
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground()", ex);

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you tried service for file download in background?

Comment: I haven't, but was thinking about it.

Comment: If you find service is good option then let me know. Thnx.

Comment: It is probably a better experience for the user if you use DownloadManager instead. This way you won't have to bother about all the 100 ways the download can stop and break.

Comment: @ALEXAnderblom  thanks for sharing that. I haven't heard of DownloadManager before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you *might* gain some speed by calling publishProgress(...) less often. Set a guard in `doInBackground(...)` so it will only be called every 100, 500, X milliseconds.

I was unable to determine how many bytes are read into your data buffer at a time. I.e. does `in.read(data)` only read up to 1024 bytes at a time? You may want to use `BufferedInputStream` instead.

And a side note: if the task completes successfully, you do not call `mWifiLock.release();`

Comment: Ok, good suggestion, I'll try it out.

Yes, it reads 1024 or less at a time. I went away from the BufferedInputStream because I was worried it would cause more memory allocations.

Yeah, good catch. I do release the lock, but I removed all the code from the onPostExecute method since it is a lot of code and it isn't related to the issue I'm having.

Comment: I think BufferedInputStream uses a default size of 8192, so that might divide the number of GC's by 8. You would be holding more memory at a time, but not much more.

Comment: You were right, calling publishProgress() so many times was causing the delays. I've posted updated code in my original question. I'm also using BufferedInputStreams and BufferedOutputStreams since it doesn't seem to be hurting anything and reduces the number of I/O accesses. Thanks for the help.

Comment: no problem. Actually answering this question made me rethink how I was doing some I/O in an app of mine :-)